# specific copy of files

Tags: files, cp

I have files and directories that have same suffix ( from 0 t0 310). and I want to copy `file(0)` to `directory(0)`, `file(10)` to `directory(10)` and go on till `file(310)` to `directory(310)`.

Is there any way that I can copy all of them at the same time?

Comment: As examples, you have listed files that have the same _prefix_, `file`. Does all filenames start with `file` and do all directory names start with `directory`?

Comment: yes, files start with file and directories start with directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over files and move them to their respective directories,

```bsh
for FILE in *; do 
if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then 
    echo mv "$FILE" "dir${FILE##file}";
fi
done
```

- `if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then`, check the `$FILE` if it's a file `-f` not a directory `-d`.
- `${FILE##file}`, (cut-up-to-last-prefix) strips `file` prefix from the fileName and keep only numeric parts.
- You need to ride of `echo` for dry run to have actual move.

Sample output:

```
file0 --> dir0
file1 --> dir1
file2 --> dir2
file3 --> dir3
```

**Update:**
In case your filename has suffix like `file##.xyz`, you can use the script as following:

```bsh
for FILE in *; do
    if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    dname="${FILE##file}";
    echo mv "$FILE" "dir${dname%.inp}";
fi
done
```

This `${dname%.inp}` part of the code (cut-up-to-first-suffix) strips `.inp` from the end of filename which `${FILE##file}` part already strip its `file` prefix before, so there will be only numeric part produce.

Or even you can use as following.

```bsh
for FILE in *; do
    if [[ -f "$FILE" ]]; then
    echo mv "$FILE" "dir${FILE//[^0-9]/}";
fi
done
```

Comment: Hi, please check updated answer about that